# Substitute Scheduling Program/Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, constraints

I am working on the following problem right now for a client that will create the most economic schedule (uses the least substitutes) given that:

- Substitutes should work in place of teacher for as consecutive a time
  as possible (*Not a huge concern)
- Subs can only work for 6 periods

So far I have a Teacher class (as shown below) and an Organizer class that actually creates the optimal schedule. Right now I am just having the program loop across the grid filling in for each substitute.

```
Teacher[] t= new Teacher[14];
Organizer o = new Organizer(t);         
o.sort();

int[][] g = o.getGrid();
```

Example input:

```
t[0] = new Teacher("Teacher 1", "Mr", new int[]{1,0,1,0,0,0,0});
t[1] = new Teacher("Teacher 2","Mr", new int[]{1,1,0,1,1,0,1});
t[2] = new Teacher("Teacher 3","Mr", new int[]{0,1,1,1,1,1,0});
t[3] = new Teacher("Teacher 4","Mr", new int[]{1,1,0,1,1,0,1});
t[4] = new Teacher("Teacher 5","Mr", new int[]{1,1,0,0,1,1,1});
t[5] = new Teacher("Teacher 6", "Mr", new int[]{1,1,1,0,0,1,1});
t[6] = new Teacher("Teacher 7", "Mr", new int[]{0,0,1,0,1,1,1});
t[7] = new Teacher("Teacher 8", "Mr", new int[]{1,1,0,0,1,1,1});
t[8] = new Teacher("Teacher 9", "Mr", new int[]{1,1,1,1,1,0,0});
t[9] = new Teacher("Teacher 10", "Mr", new int[]{0,0,0,1,1,1,0});
t[10] = new Teacher("Teacher 11", "Mr", new int[]{0,0,1,0,0,1,1});
t[11] = new Teacher("Teacher 12", "Mr", new int[]{0,0,1,1,0,1,0});
t[12] = new Teacher("Teacher 13", "Mr", new int[]{1,1,1,1,0,0,0});
t[13] = new Teacher("Teacher 14", "Mr", new int[]{1,1,0,1,1,0,1});
```

Output for the above (with the algorithm I am using):

```
                    P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6  P7
Teacher 1           1   -   1   -   -   -   -
Teacher 2           2   1   -   1   1   -   1
Teacher 3           -   2   2   2   2   2   -
Teacher 4           3   3   -   3   3   -   3
Teacher 5           4   4   -   -   4   3   4
Teacher 6           5   5   4   -   -   4   5
Teacher 7           -   -   5   -   5   5   6
Teacher 8           6   6   -   -   6   6   7
Teacher 9           7   7   6   7   7   -   -
Teacher 10          -   -   -   8   8   7   -
Teacher 11          -   -   8   -   -   8   8
Teacher 12          -   -   9   9   -   9   -
Teacher 13          8   9   10  10  -   -   -
Teacher 14          9   10  -   11  9   -   10
```

As you can see, the program just loops across the valid spaces, filling them in with subs until the sub reaches its max teaching periods, and then begins a new sub. The thing is, I have been able to get the number of subs used down to 10 when doing it by hand, so I have been trying to find a more efficient algorithm, with no avail.

For this input, the minimum number of subs used is 9 (constrained by P2 column), so I would like to see if there is any possible way that I can accomplish that number, or 10 subs at the very least. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For each column figure out how many open spaces there are.

Place each sub first into the columns with the most open spaces, and then randomly.  This algorithm will solve your given problem with 10 subs.

In your specific example, there are 59 spaces.  Given that each sub can only fill 6 spaces, 10 is the smallest number of subs that can work.  I believe that it will always find an optimal solution.

(I have ignored your consecutive days rule.  The "then randomly" rule can be replaced with something that tries to optimize that...)